# Java -Xms50g mmap fails with ENOMEM, TBs of RAM and no user limits

Tags: java, linux, out-of-memory, 64-bit, mmap

I try to run some jar on a x64 Linux machine with multiple TBs (no typo) of physical RAM.

```
java -XX:+AggressiveOpts -XX:-UseGCOverheadLimit -Xmx500g -Xms50g -jar myjar.jar
```

It fails immediately (before actually doing anything with the jar) with the following message. With `-Xms10g` the program starts normally, until it is eventually killed with a similar error message.

```
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: INFO: os::commit_memory(0x00002ad6cb000000, 35791568896, 0) failed; error='Cannot allocate memory' (errno=12)
#
# There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
# Native memory allocation (mmap) failed to map 35791568896 bytes for committing reserved memory.
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /home/user/hs_err_pid84077.log
```

There exist many similar questions on this site, but this case seems to be different.

For one thing, there are no relevant user limits:

```
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 12385572
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) unlimited
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 4096
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) unlimited
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 12385572
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

Not even close to 90% RAM yet, nor reaching the maximum number of memory maps (see end).

```
$ sysctl vm.overcommit_memory
vm.overcommit_memory = 2
$ sysctl vm.overcommit_ratio 
vm.overcommit_ratio = 90
$ sysctl vm.max_map_count 
vm.max_map_count = 65530
```

Furthermore, the address space seems to be large enough. There is also plenty of memory available:

```
$ cat /proc/meminfo
MemTotal:       3170746916 kB
MemFree:        2753352244 kB
MemAvailable:   3031595960 kB
Buffers:         3408332 kB
Cached:         269276892 kB
SwapCached:            0 kB
Active:         335462768 kB
Inactive:       63212304 kB
Active(anon):   125994412 kB
Inactive(anon):    34048 kB
Active(file):   209468356 kB
Inactive(file): 63178256 kB
Unevictable:        3660 kB
Mlocked:            3660 kB
SwapTotal:             0 kB
SwapFree:              0 kB
Dirty:                 8 kB
Writeback:             0 kB
AnonPages:      126321108 kB
Mapped:           113552 kB
Shmem:             36220 kB
Slab:            9810220 kB
SReclaimable:    9236880 kB
SUnreclaim:       573340 kB
KernelStack:       39840 kB
PageTables:      1737088 kB
NFS_Unstable:          4 kB
Bounce:                0 kB
WritebackTmp:          0 kB
CommitLimit:    2853672224 kB
Committed_AS:   2839244796 kB
VmallocTotal:   34359738367 kB
VmallocUsed:           0 kB
VmallocChunk:          0 kB
HardwareCorrupted:     0 kB
AnonHugePages:  113201152 kB
CmaTotal:              0 kB
CmaFree:               0 kB
HugePages_Total:       0
HugePages_Free:        0
HugePages_Rsvd:        0
HugePages_Surp:        0
Hugepagesize:       2048 kB
DirectMap4k:      604864 kB
DirectMap2M:    51777536 kB
DirectMap1G:    3168796672 kB
```

In the relevant part of the output of strace, it can be seen that the program tried to mmap 33 GiB and got an `ENOMEM` there:

```
[pid 83157] mmap(NULL, 536870912000, PROT_NONE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS|MAP_NORESERVE, -1, 0) = 0x2b06d7000000
[pid 83157] mmap(NULL, 1048580096, PROT_NONE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS|MAP_NORESERVE, -1, 0) = 0x2b83d7000000
[pid 83157] mmap(0x2b8415800000, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x2b8415800000
[pid 83157] mmap(0x2b5a2c580000, 17895522304, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x2b5a2c580000
[pid 83157] mmap(0x2b8400aaa000, 34955264, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x2b8400aaa000
[pid 83157] mmap(0x2b06d7000000, 35791568896, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = -1 ENOMEM (Cannot allocate memory)
[pid 83157] write(2, "OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning"..., 34OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: ) = 34
[pid 83157] write(2, "INFO: os::commit_memory(0x00002b"..., 109INFO: os::commit_memory(0x00002b06d7000000, 35791568896, 0) failed; error='Cannot allocate memory' (errno=12)) = 109
```

In the log file that was written, Java confirmed that at the moment of throwing the error, there was really plenty of space:

```
Memory: 4k page, physical 3170746916k(2783572928k free), swap 0k(0k free)
```

What else could cause this? Is that address actually still on the heap? Because pmap shows this (different run):

```
113990:   java -XX:+AggressiveOpts -XX:-UseGCOverheadLimit -Xmx500g -Xms10g -jar myjar.jar 24
0000000000400000      4K r-x-- /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java
0000000000600000      4K r---- /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java
0000000000601000      4K rw--- /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java
0000000001ca6000    132K rw---   [ anon ]
00002b9a14bc1000    152K r-x-- /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so
00002b9a14be7000      8K rw---   [ anon ]
00002b9a14be9000      4K -----   [ anon ]
00002b9a14bea000      4K rw---   [ anon ]
00002b9a14beb000     32K rw-s- /tmp/hsperfdata_user/113990
00002b9a14bf3000      4K r--s- /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/ext/jaccess.jar
00002b9a14bf4000     20K r--s- /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar
00002b9a14bf9000     12K r--s- /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/ext/icedtea-sound.jar
00002b9a14bfc000    108K r--s- /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/ext/cldrdata.jar
00002b9a14c17000     16K r--s- /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/ext/sunpkcs11.jar
00002b9a14c1b000      4K r--s- /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/ext/zipfs.jar
00002b9a14c1c000      8K r--s- /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/ext/dnsns.jar
00002b9a14c1e000      8K r--s- /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/ext/sunec.jar
00002b9a14c22000     16K rw---   [ anon ]
00002b9a14c26000     12K -----   [ anon ]
00002b9a14c29000   1692K rw---   [ anon ]
00002b9a14dd0000     40K r--s- /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/ext/localedata.jar
00002b9a14dda000     36K r--s- /home/user/myjar.jar
00002b9a14de6000      4K r---- /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so
00002b9a14de7000      4K rw--- /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so
00002b9a14de8000      4K rw---   [ anon ]
00002b9a14de9000     52K r-x-- /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/jli/libjli.so
00002b9a14df6000   2048K ----- /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/jli/libjli.so
00002b9a14ff6000      4K r---- /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/jli/libjli.so
00002b9a14ff7000      4K rw--- /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/jli/libjli.so
00002b9a14ff8000   1792K r-x-- /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
00002b9a151b8000   2048K ----- /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
00002b9a153b8000     16K r---- /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
00002b9a153bc000      8K rw--- /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
00002b9a153be000     16K rw---   [ anon ]
00002b9a153c2000    100K r-x-- /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1.2.8
00002b9a153db000   2044K ----- /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1.2.8
00002b9a155da000      4K r---- /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1.2.8
00002b9a155db000      4K rw--- /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1.2.8
00002b9a155dc000     12K r-x-- /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.23.so
00002b9a155df000   2044K ----- /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.23.so
00002b9a157de000      4K r---- /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.23.so
00002b9a157df000      4K rw--- /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.23.so
00002b9a157e0000     96K r-x-- /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.23.so
00002b9a157f8000   2044K ----- /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.23.so
00002b9a159f7000      4K r---- /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.23.so
00002b9a159f8000      4K rw--- /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.23.so
00002b9a159f9000     16K rw---   [ anon ]
00002b9a159fd000  12624K r-x-- /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
00002b9a16651000   2048K ----- /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
00002b9a16851000    588K r---- /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
00002b9a168e4000    164K rw--- /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
00002b9a1690d000    192K rw---   [ anon ]
00002b9a1693d000   1480K r-x-- /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21
00002b9a16aaf000   2048K ----- /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21
00002b9a16caf000     40K r---- /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21
00002b9a16cb9000      8K rw--- /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21
00002b9a16cbb000     16K rw---   [ anon ]
00002b9a16cbf000   1056K r-x-- /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.23.so
00002b9a16dc7000   2044K ----- /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.23.so
00002b9a16fc6000      4K r---- /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.23.so
00002b9a16fc7000      4K rw--- /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.23.so
00002b9a16fc8000     88K r-x-- /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
00002b9a16fde000   2044K ----- /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
00002b9a171dd000      4K rw--- /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
00002b9a171de000     28K r-x-- /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt-2.23.so
00002b9a171e5000   2044K ----- /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt-2.23.so
00002b9a173e4000      4K r---- /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt-2.23.so
00002b9a173e5000      4K rw--- /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt-2.23.so
00002b9a173e6000     60K r-x-- /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/libverify.so
00002b9a173f5000   2044K ----- /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/libverify.so
00002b9a175f4000      8K r---- /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/libverify.so
00002b9a175f6000      4K rw--- /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/libverify.so
00002b9a175f7000    180K r-x-- /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/libjava.so
00002b9a17624000   2044K ----- /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/libjava.so
00002b9a17823000      4K r---- /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/libjava.so
00002b9a17824000      8K rw--- /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/libjava.so
00002b9a17826000     44K r-x-- /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_files-2.23.so
00002b9a17831000   2044K ----- /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_files-2.23.so
00002b9a17a30000      4K r---- /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_files-2.23.so
00002b9a17a31000      4K rw--- /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_files-2.23.so
00002b9a17a32000     24K rw---   [ anon ]
00002b9a17a38000     32K r-x-- /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/libzip.so
00002b9a17a40000   2044K ----- /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/libzip.so
00002b9a17c3f000      4K r---- /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/libzip.so
00002b9a17c40000      4K rw--- /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/libzip.so
00002b9a17c41000      4K -----   [ anon ]
00002b9a17c42000   1024K rw---   [ anon ]
00002b9a17d42000      4K -----   [ anon ]
00002b9a17d43000   1024K rw---   [ anon ]
00002b9a17e43000      4K -----   [ anon ]
00002b9a17e44000   1496K rw---   [ anon ]
00002b9a17fba000    108K r--s- /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/ext/nashorn.jar
00002b9a18000000  13096K rw---   [ anon ]
00002b9a18cca000  52440K -----   [ anon ]
00002b9a1c000000   4864K rwx--   [ anon ]
00002b9a1c4c0000 240896K -----   [ anon ]
00002b9a2b000000     76K rw---   [ anon ]
00002b9a2b013000   3764K -----   [ anon ]
00002b9a2b400000 6990848K rw---   [ anon ]
00002b9bd5f00000 342534656K -----   [ anon ]
00002bed80980000 11359232K rw---   [ anon ]
00002bf035e80000 163403264K -----   [ anon ]
00002c172b400000  13656K rw---   [ anon ]
00002c172c156000 669008K -----   [ anon ]
00002c1754eaa000  22192K rw---   [ anon ]
00002c1756456000 319144K -----   [ anon ]
00002c1769c00000  13660K rw---   [ anon ]
00002c176a957000 669012K -----   [ anon ]
00002c17936ac000      4K -----   [ anon ]
00002c17936ad000   1024K rw---   [ anon ]
00002c17937ad000      4K -----   [ anon ]
00002c17937ae000   1024K rw---   [ anon ]
00002c17938ae000      4K -----   [ anon ]
00002c17938af000   1024K rw---   [ anon ]
00002c17939af000      4K -----   [ anon ]
00002c17939b0000   1024K rw---   [ anon ]
00002c1793ab0000      4K -----   [ anon ]
00002c1793ab1000   1024K rw---   [ anon ]
00002c1793bb1000      4K -----   [ anon ]
00002c1793bb2000   1024K rw---   [ anon ]
00002c1793cb2000      4K -----   [ anon ]
00002c1793cb3000   1024K rw---   [ anon ]
00002c1793db3000      4K -----   [ anon ]
00002c1793db4000   1024K rw---   [ anon ]
00002c1793eb4000      4K -----   [ anon ]
00002c1793eb5000   1024K rw---   [ anon ]
00002c1793fb5000      4K -----   [ anon ]
[... redacted, I used too many characters ...]
00002c17974eb000   1024K rw---   [ anon ]
00002c17975eb000      4K -----   [ anon ]
00002c17975ec000   1024K rw---   [ anon ]
00002c17976ec000      4K -----   [ anon ]
00002c17976ed000   1024K rw---   [ anon ]
00002c17977ed000      4K -----   [ anon ]
00002c17977ee000   1024K rw---   [ anon ]
00002c17978ee000      4K -----   [ anon ]
00002c17978ef000   1024K rw---   [ anon ]
00002c17979ef000      4K -----   [ anon ]
00002c17979f0000   1024K rw---   [ anon ]
00002c1797af0000      4K -----   [ anon ]
00002c1797af1000   1024K rw---   [ anon ]
00002c1797bf1000      4K -----   [ anon ]
00002c1797bf2000   1024K rw---   [ anon ]
00002c1797cf2000      4K -----   [ anon ]
00002c1797cf3000   1024K rw---   [ anon ]
00002c1797df3000      4K -----   [ anon ]
00002c1797df4000   1024K rw---   [ anon ]
00002c1797ef4000      4K -----   [ anon ]
00002c1797ef5000   1024K rw---   [ anon ]
00002c1797ff5000      4K -----   [ anon ]
00002c1797ff6000   1024K rw---   [ anon ]
00002c17980f6000      4K -----   [ anon ]
00002c17980f7000  45632K rw---   [ anon ]
00002c179ad87000   3584K -----   [ anon ]
00002c179b107000   1848K r--s- /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/rt.jar
00002c179b2d5000  13364K rw---   [ anon ]
00002c179c000000    132K rw---   [ anon ]
00002c179c021000  65404K -----   [ anon ]
00002c17a0000000    132K rw---   [ anon ]
00002c17a0021000  65404K -----   [ anon ]
00002c17a4000000    132K rw---   [ anon ]
00002c17a4021000  65404K -----   [ anon ]
00002c17a8000000    132K rw---   [ anon ]
00002c17a8021000  65404K -----   [ anon ]
00002c17ac000000    132K rw---   [ anon ]
00002c17ac021000  65404K -----   [ anon ]
00002c17b0000000    132K rw---   [ anon ]
00002c17b0021000  65404K -----   [ anon ]
00002c17b4000000    132K rw---   [ anon ]
00002c17b4021000  65404K -----   [ anon ]
00002c17b8000000    132K rw---   [ anon ]
00002c17b8021000  65404K -----   [ anon ]
00002c17bc000000    132K rw---   [ anon ]
00002c17bc021000  65404K -----   [ anon ]
00002c17c0000000    132K rw---   [ anon ]
00002c17c0021000  65404K -----   [ anon ]
00002c17c4000000    132K rw---   [ anon ]
00002c17c4021000  65404K -----   [ anon ]
00002c17c8000000    132K rw---   [ anon ]
00002c17c8021000  65404K -----   [ anon ]
00002c17cc000000    132K rw---   [ anon ]
00002c17cc021000  65404K -----   [ anon ]
00002c17d0000000    132K rw---   [ anon ]
00002c17d0021000  65404K -----   [ anon ]
00002c17d4000000    132K rw---   [ anon ]
00002c17d4021000  65404K -----   [ anon ]
00002c17d8000000    132K rw---   [ anon ]
00002c17d8021000  65404K -----   [ anon ]
00002c17dc000000    132K rw---   [ anon ]
00002c17dc021000  65404K -----   [ anon ]
00002c17e0000000    132K rw---   [ anon ]
00002c17e0021000  65404K -----   [ anon ]
00002c17e4000000    132K rw---   [ anon ]
00002c17e4021000  65404K -----   [ anon ]
00002c17e8000000    132K rw---   [ anon ]
00002c17e8021000  65404K -----   [ anon ]
00002c17ec000000    132K rw---   [ anon ]
00002c17ec021000  65404K -----   [ anon ]
00002c17f0000000    132K rw---   [ anon ]
00002c17f0021000  65404K -----   [ anon ]
00002c17f4000000    132K rw---   [ anon ]
00002c17f4021000  65404K -----   [ anon ]
00002c17f8000000    132K rw---   [ anon ]
00002c17f8021000  65404K -----   [ anon ]
00002c17fc000000    132K rw---   [ anon ]
00002c17fc021000  65404K -----   [ anon ]
00002c1800000000    132K rw---   [ anon ]
00002c1800021000  65404K -----   [ anon ]
00002c1804000000    132K rw---   [ anon ]
00002c1804021000  65404K -----   [ anon ]
00002c1808000000    132K rw---   [ anon ]
00002c1808021000  65404K -----   [ anon ]
00002c180c000000    132K rw---   [ anon ]
00002c180c021000  65404K -----   [ anon ]
00002c1810000000    132K rw---   [ anon ]
00002c1810021000  65404K -----   [ anon ]
00002c1814000000    132K rw---   [ anon ]
00002c1814021000  65404K -----   [ anon ]
00002c1818000000    132K rw---   [ anon ]
00002c1818021000  65404K -----   [ anon ]
00002c181c000000    132K rw---   [ anon ]
00002c181c021000  65404K -----   [ anon ]
00002c1820000000    132K rw---   [ anon ]
00002c1820021000  65404K -----   [ anon ]
00002c1824000000    132K rw---   [ anon ]
00002c1824021000  65404K -----   [ anon ]
00002c1828000000    132K rw---   [ anon ]
00002c1828021000  65404K -----   [ anon ]
00002c182c000000    132K rw---   [ anon ]
00002c182c021000  65404K -----   [ anon ]
00002c1830000000    132K rw---   [ anon ]
00002c1830021000  65404K -----   [ anon ]
00002c1834000000    132K rw---   [ anon ]
00002c1834021000  65404K -----   [ anon ]
00002c1838000000    132K rw---   [ anon ]
00002c1838021000  65404K -----   [ anon ]
00002c183c000000    132K rw---   [ anon ]
00002c183c021000  65404K -----   [ anon ]
00002c1840000000    132K rw---   [ anon ]
00002c1840021000  65404K -----   [ anon ]
00002c1844000000    132K rw---   [ anon ]
00002c1844021000  65404K -----   [ anon ]
00002c1848000000    132K rw---   [ anon ]
00002c1848021000  65404K -----   [ anon ]
00002c184c000000    132K rw---   [ anon ]
00002c184c021000  65404K -----   [ anon ]
00002c1850000000    132K rw---   [ anon ]
00002c1850021000  65404K -----   [ anon ]
00002c1854000000    132K rw---   [ anon ]
00002c1854021000  65404K -----   [ anon ]
00002c1858000000    132K rw---   [ anon ]
00002c1858021000  65404K -----   [ anon ]
00002c185c000000    132K rw---   [ anon ]
00002c185c021000  65404K -----   [ anon ]
00002c1860000000    132K rw---   [ anon ]
00002c1860021000  65404K -----   [ anon ]
00002c1864000000    132K rw---   [ anon ]
00002c1864021000  65404K -----   [ anon ]
00002c1868000000    132K rw---   [ anon ]
00002c1868021000  65404K -----   [ anon ]
00002c186c000000    132K rw---   [ anon ]
00002c186c021000  65404K -----   [ anon ]
00002c1870000000    132K rw---   [ anon ]
00002c1870021000  65404K -----   [ anon ]
00002c1874000000    132K rw---   [ anon ]
00002c1874021000  65404K -----   [ anon ]
00002c1878000000    132K rw---   [ anon ]
00002c1878021000  65404K -----   [ anon ]
00002c187c000000    132K rw---   [ anon ]
00002c187c021000  65404K -----   [ anon ]
00002c1880000000    132K rw---   [ anon ]
00002c1880021000  65404K -----   [ anon ]
00002c1884000000  64764K rw---   [ anon ]
00002c1888000000    132K rw---   [ anon ]
00002c1888021000  65404K -----   [ anon ]
00002c188c000000    132K rw---   [ anon ]
00002c188c021000  65404K -----   [ anon ]
00002c1890000000    132K rw---   [ anon ]
00002c1890021000  65404K -----   [ anon ]
00002c1894000000    132K rw---   [ anon ]
00002c1894021000  65404K -----   [ anon ]
00002c1898000000  64764K rw---   [ anon ]
00002c189c000000    132K rw---   [ anon ]
00002c189c021000  65404K -----   [ anon ]
00002c18a0000000    132K rw---   [ anon ]
00002c18a0021000  65404K -----   [ anon ]
00002c18a4000000    132K rw---   [ anon ]
00002c18a4021000  65404K -----   [ anon ]
00002c18a8000000  64764K rw---   [ anon ]
00002c18ac000000    132K rw---   [ anon ]
00002c18ac021000  65404K -----   [ anon ]
00002c18b0000000    132K rw---   [ anon ]
00002c18b0021000  65404K -----   [ anon ]
00002c18b4000000    132K rw---   [ anon ]
00002c18b4021000  65404K -----   [ anon ]
00002c18b8000000    132K rw---   [ anon ]
00002c18b8021000  65404K -----   [ anon ]
00002c18bc000000    132K rw---   [ anon ]
00002c18bc021000  65404K -----   [ anon ]
00002c18c0000000    132K rw---   [ anon ]
00002c18c0021000  65404K -----   [ anon ]
00002c18c4000000  35980K rw---   [ anon ]
00002c18c6323000      4K -----   [ anon ]
00002c18c6324000   1024K rw---   [ anon ]
00002c18c6424000     12K -----   [ anon ]
00002c18c6427000   1016K rw---   [ anon ]
00002c18c6525000     12K -----   [ anon ]
00002c18c6528000   1016K rw---   [ anon ]
00002c18c6626000   8252K r---- /usr/lib/locale/locale-archive
00002c18c6e35000     12K -----   [ anon ]
00002c18c6e38000   1016K rw---   [ anon ]
00002c18c6f36000     12K -----   [ anon ]
00002c18c6f39000   1016K rw---   [ anon ]
00002c18c7037000     12K -----   [ anon ]
00002c18c703a000   1016K rw---   [ anon ]
00002c18c7138000     12K -----   [ anon ]
00002c18c713b000   1016K rw---   [ anon ]
00002c18c7239000     12K -----   [ anon ]
00002c18c723c000   1016K rw---   [ anon ]
00002c18c733a000     12K -----   [ anon ]
00002c18c733d000   1016K rw---   [ anon ]
00002c18c743b000     12K -----   [ anon ]
00002c18c743e000   1016K rw---   [ anon ]
00002c18c753c000     12K -----   [ anon ]
00002c18c753f000   1016K rw---   [ anon ]
00002c18c763d000     12K -----   [ anon ]
00002c18c7640000   1016K rw---   [ anon ]
00002c18c773e000     12K -----   [ anon ]
00002c18c7741000   1016K rw---   [ anon ]
00002c18c783f000     12K -----   [ anon ]
00002c18c7842000   1016K rw---   [ anon ]
00002c18c7940000     12K -----   [ anon ]
00002c18c7943000   1016K rw---   [ anon ]
00002c18c7a41000     12K -----   [ anon ]
00002c18c7a44000   1016K rw---   [ anon ]
00002c18c7b42000     12K -----   [ anon ]
00002c18c7b45000   1016K rw---   [ anon ]
00002c18c7c43000     12K -----   [ anon ]
00002c18c7c46000   1016K rw---   [ anon ]
00002c18c7d44000     12K -----   [ anon ]
00002c18c7d47000   1016K rw---   [ anon ]
00002c18c7e45000     12K -----   [ anon ]
00002c18c7e48000   1016K rw---   [ anon ]
00002c18c8000000    132K rw---   [ anon ]
00002c18c8021000  65404K -----   [ anon ]
00002c18cc000000    132K rw---   [ anon ]
00002c18cc021000  65404K -----   [ anon ]
00002c18d0000000    132K rw---   [ anon ]
00002c18d0021000  65404K -----   [ anon ]
00002c18d4000000     12K -----   [ anon ]
00002c18d4003000   1016K rw---   [ anon ]
00002c18d4101000     12K -----   [ anon ]
00002c18d4104000   1016K rw---   [ anon ]
00002c18d4202000     12K -----   [ anon ]
00002c18d4205000   1016K rw---   [ anon ]
00002c18d4303000      4K -----   [ anon ]
00002c18d4304000   1024K rw---   [ anon ]
00002c18d8000000    132K rw---   [ anon ]
00002c18d8021000  65404K -----   [ anon ]
00002c18e0000000    132K rw---   [ anon ]
00002c18e0021000  65404K -----   [ anon ]
00002c18e4000000    132K rw---   [ anon ]
00002c18e4021000  65404K -----   [ anon ]
00002c18e8000000    132K rw---   [ anon ]
00002c18e8021000  65404K -----   [ anon ]
00002c18ec000000 17408000K rw---   [ anon ]
00002c1d14000000    132K rw---   [ anon ]
00002c1d14021000  65404K -----   [ anon ]
00002c1d18000000    132K rw---   [ anon ]
00002c1d18021000  65404K -----   [ anon ]
00002c1d1c000000    132K rw---   [ anon ]
00002c1d1c021000  65404K -----   [ anon ]
00002c1d20000000    132K rw---   [ anon ]
00002c1d20021000  65404K -----   [ anon ]
00002c1d24000000    808K rw---   [ anon ]
00002c1d240ca000  64728K -----   [ anon ]
00002c1d28000000    876K rw---   [ anon ]
00002c1d280db000  64660K -----   [ anon ]
00002c1d2c000000    404K rw---   [ anon ]
00002c1d2c065000  65132K -----   [ anon ]
00002c1d30000000    552K rw---   [ anon ]
00002c1d3008a000  64984K -----   [ anon ]
00002c1d34000000   1044K rw---   [ anon ]
00002c1d34105000  64492K -----   [ anon ]
00002c1d38000000    964K rw---   [ anon ]
00002c1d380f1000  64572K -----   [ anon ]
00002c1d3c000000    980K rw---   [ anon ]
00002c1d3c0f5000  64556K -----   [ anon ]
00002c1d40000000   1688K rw---   [ anon ]
00002c1d401a6000  63848K -----   [ anon ]
00002c1d44000000   1336K rw---   [ anon ]
00002c1d4414e000  64200K -----   [ anon ]
00002c1d48000000   7640K rw---   [ anon ]
00002c1d48776000  57896K -----   [ anon ]
00002c1d4c000000   2956K rw---   [ anon ]
00002c1d4c2e3000  62580K -----   [ anon ]
00002c1d50000000   3140K rw---   [ anon ]
00002c1d50311000  62396K -----   [ anon ]
00002c1d54000000    756K rw---   [ anon ]
00002c1d540bd000  64780K -----   [ anon ]
00002c1d58000000    760K rw---   [ anon ]
00002c1d580be000  64776K -----   [ anon ]
00002c1d5c000000    672K rw---   [ anon ]
00002c1d5c0a8000  64864K -----   [ anon ]
00002c1d60000000    608K rw---   [ anon ]
00002c1d60098000  64928K -----   [ anon ]
00002c1d64000000    512K rw---   [ anon ]
00002c1d64080000  65024K -----   [ anon ]
00002c1d68000000   1248K rw---   [ anon ]
00002c1d68138000  64288K -----   [ anon ]
00002c1d6c000000    132K rw---   [ anon ]
00002c1d6c021000  65404K -----   [ anon ]
00002c1d70000000    132K rw---   [ anon ]
00002c1d70021000  65404K -----   [ anon ]
00007ffd59070000    132K rw---   [ stack ]
00007ffd5918b000      8K r----   [ anon ]
00007ffd5918d000      8K r-x--   [ anon ]
ffffffffff600000      4K r-x--   [ anon ]
 total        550859784K
```

Comment: It seems you already did your research, but in case you missed this one: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/largememory-jsp-137182.html (java large memory support documentation)

Comment: Just out of curiosity what happens when you do something like: `java -Xmx500g -version`

Comment: I'm not root on this machine, so I can't enable HugePages. `-Xmx500g` works fine for a while (as in: at least the program starts), but eventually it still gives the same error, long before actually reaching 500 GiB.